# JCA accesses file in cluster

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cluster-computing, jca

In a Java EE environment, I want to use JCA to access a file. The file will be updated hourly. But the complex thing is the Java EE environment will be in a cluster.

Does the JCA specification support connections in a cluster?

Answer (score 0):

The latest JCA 1.6 specification in Java EE 6 does have some explicit support for clusters, but the way I understood it this is more for distributing work. Nevertheless it might be of some help. See this for some overview: http://java.dzone.com/articles/jboss-jca

All in all, details about JCA seem be hard to obtain. The API is sort of a black art.